# Lubuntu download/upgrade

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu

have the alternate ISO downloaded.32 bit.i could not download torrent.now i seem to have to download more and more just to get into the files.i simply want the best way to install this operating system without a bunch of b.s.i am doing my best to get this right the first time.i am new to linux and i am sure i am missing something,i get that.next will i need something i am missing such as drivers or something?i am trying to ask good questions.my ultimate goal is to completely erase/delete windows xp from my inspiron 1500 notebook(present from mom,not getting rid of it!)and using lubuntu. plz b patient.i am a troglodyte(knuckledragger),i work in the construction&oilfield industry.thankyou.b blessed.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you encountered a problem downloading lubuntu or during the ubuntu install? From your question I can't really see what you're asking.

Comment: have downloaded the 32 bit ISO.its on my notebook.but have had to download bitzipper to even open the program,then free file viewer to see more.do i need to use a program and turn this into a boot disk?should i find and use a bit torrent program and down load the torrent version instead?i look forward to totally eliminating windows,never been totally happy with it.the idea of it disappearing of my notebook makes me wanna holler touchdown!but i dont want to end up with a notebook i cant use at all.please advise.thanks and b blessed again.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have downloaded the iso don't use any programs to try and open or unpack it. 
You need a usb stick (preferably between 2 and 8GB) and then follow this easy three step guide here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows 
to load the iso onto your usb stick and make it bootable.
After that just reboot your notebook and select the usb stick as the boot device.

Comment: i did as instructed.i am able to load/try lubuntu without loading.i have one issue,my wifi works,with windows,but is not recognized by lubuntu.is this a additional driver/software issue that i need to get from a repository for my distro or,do i have an issue that needs fixed prior to loading the new OS.iam hoping i can take care of the issue alone.but as i said before,i am brand new to any form of linux.so far i think the new OS is great,but without internet i cant use.thanks any and evrybody.